# Linking SASM to C libraries

Tags: c, windows, assembly, linker, sasm

When I try to link C to SASM (using NASM), it fails to identify `_printf`. I am using it for Windows too

```
global _main
extern _printf
section .data
message db "Hello World",13,10,0
section .text
_main:
    ;write your code here
    ;printf “Hello World”
    push message
    call _printf
    add esp, 4
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Expected output would it to be built and run with "Hello World".
What I get is:

```
[15:46:18] Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.o:C:\Users\_\App:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_printf'
c:/program files (x86)/sasm/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

[image: My settings]

Assembly Options: `--gprefix _ -f win32 $SOURCE$ -l $LSTOUTPUT$ -o $PROGRAM.OBJ$`

Linking options: `$PROGRAM.OBJ$ $MACRO.OBJ$ -g -o $PROGRAM$ -m32`